# HTML accesskey attribute

Tags: html

What does this mean: "the value must be an ordered set of unique space-separated tokens"?

Comment: a little more context might help with getting an answer.  Is this an error, general question, etc.

Comment: @confusedGeek general question

Comment: ok, I think @Ian covered it better than I could have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the attribute:

- can accept multiple keys
- each key name (token) may not contain spaces
- a space must come between each key name
- you shouldn't use the same key name twice
- the order of the keys is important

I think `accesskey` in HTML 4 can only accept a single key character, but there is a [proposal in HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute) for it to accept multiple characters (tokens) so if a device does not have a key for the first character specified it can bind the element to the next, and so on.